# Apache cannot start on xampp server httpd.exe

Tags: apache, xampp

when  I want to start the apache server i have this error message

> the entry point _register_onexit_fuction is not found ...

I hope that someone could help me !!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX4GN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Windows path (`System Environment Variables`)and remove any path to a former install.